# Double % formatting question for printf in Java

Tags: java, printf

`%s` is a string in `printf`, and %d is a decimal I thought...yet when putting in

```
writer.printf("%d dollars is the balance of %s\r\n", bal, nm);
```

..an exception is thrown telling me that `%d` != lang.double. Ideas?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`%d` is for integers use `%f` instead, it works for both `float` and `double` types:

```
double d = 1.2;
float f = 1.2f;
System.out.printf("%f %f",d,f); // prints 1.200000 1.200000
```

Comment: BTW, it only prints 6 scale after decimal point, could print more like this: `%.8f` (it prints 8 scale).

Comment: So the precision can go up to 15 using %f?

Answer (score 31):

Yes, **`%d`** means decimal, but it means **decimal number system**, not decimal point.

Further, as a complement to the former post, you can also control the number of decimal points to show. Try this,

```
System.out.printf("%.2f %.1f",d,f); // prints 1.20 1.2
```

For more please refer to the [API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 9):

Following is the list of conversion characters that you may use in the printf:

```
%d – for signed decimal integer

%f – for the floating point

%o – octal number

%c – for a character

%s – a string

%i – use for integer base 10

%u – for unsigned decimal number

%x – hexadecimal number

%% – for writing % (percentage)

%n – for new line = \n
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, %d is for decimal (integer), double expect %f. But simply using %f will default to up to precision 6. To print all of the precision digits for a double, you can pass it via string as:

```
System.out.printf("%s \r\n",String.valueOf(d));
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%s \r\n",Double.toString(d));
```

This is what println do by default:

```
System.out.println(d)
```

(and terminates the line)